# How to remove extra to the right of the input button?

Tags: html, css, psd

Ok I'm recreating a PSD I found online for practise. In the header there is a search bar and button. To the right of the button there is extra content taking up space, which I can't get rid of.

I have added a jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/jb7j6ysz/

Please ensure the preview is expanded to the left as much as possible

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Education Compaony</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="branding">
        <h2>Education Department</h2>
        <h5>A free PSD template</h5>
      </div> <!-- /.Branding -->
    <div class="directory">
      <div class="search">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
      </div> <!-- /.Search -->
      <div class="index">
        <ul>
          <li>A - Z index | </li>
          <li>Studenet Login | </li>
          <li>Staff Login </li>
        </ul>
      </div> <!-- /.Index -->
    </div> <!-- /.Directory -->
  </div> <!-- /.Header -->
  </body>
</html>

/* Font Import */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header{
  height: 95px;;
  background-color: #FCD05D;
  color: #3A302E;
  font-family: 'Lora', sans-serif;
}

.branding {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.branding h2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.branding h5 {
  margin-top: -20px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.directory {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 200px;
}

.search {
  background-color: black;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 1px 0px 5px 12px;
}

.search input[type=text] {
  background-color: #FCD05D;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.search input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #595657;
  color: #FCD05D;
  border: 2px solid #595657;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.index ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: -0;
}

.index li {
  margin-top: -20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-flex;
  word-spacing: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Your search bar out of header can you elaborate what you want ?

Comment: add width:70% to your input or any number according to your need

Comment: set width for either directory or search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra space is coming from the `ul` where your links are. Since the width is auto, the list section has a greater width than your search section so the search section takes on that width.

You can set `padding: 0` to the `ul` list to reduce some of the space. It has a natural padding to the left. This will still leave some space on the right because of the length of your list. You can set width to the search area to prevent the list from wrapping. Or you could make the search section float left but you will need to adjust padding to make it look symmetrical

Here is an example

https://jsfiddle.net/jb7j6ysz/3/

```
.search {
  background-color: black;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 1px 12px 5px 12px;
  float: left;
}
.index ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

I used float for the new fiddle and added padding 0 to the `ul`. Also adjusted the padding on `.search`

Comment: Thanks you. Best answer!

Answer (score 0):

The index div is in the way. Update your css with this

```
.index{
  position: absolute;
  display:block;
  left: 40%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The extra space is coming because of your Ul items. Add this in your css

```
 ul{
  padding-left:0px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is to do with the width of the `.index` div. Both it and your search bar are contained within the same `.directory` div. Because both are block-level elements with their width set to the default `auto`, they take on the width of their parent, which in this case is set by the largest child, the `.index` div.

By setting the search bar to `display: inline-block;`, it will only take up as much width as it needs.

```
.search {
  ...
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Additionally, the `ul` used for the `.index` div has `padding-left` by default, which you may want to set otherwise.